Need help resolving a conflict that a deleted file is causing
Hello I made a mistake in deleting a file from my project and I pushed that change already. I want to permanently revert to a build that still has that file in my project. When I first started to revert my files I made a clone of the commit that still had my file in it. Along the way I managed to get a conflict with unmerged files. This made any commands that I looked up not work such as
git revert --no-commit HASHGOESHERE..HEAD git commit git push
My deleted file shows up in my VSCode but it has a conflict on it saying "deleted by us"
I know I need to resolve this conflict before preceding. Any ideas how I can resolve this conflict? I don't understand a lot of the commands that I see are recommended and some of them that I was brave enough to try I get an unmerged conflict.

Sure, let me google that for you...

This question is similar to: Restore deleted files in github repository after git push -f. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

When you say "I want to revert to...", do you mean you want to make new commits that undo the mistake, or do you mean you want to have a state as if the wrong commit never happened?
